# Can PWA use external storage along with the internal storage in mobile devices?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I haven't found anything about if external storage complements internal storage in mobile devices, and more important if PWA uses the total memory of both or just internal memory.

Any information related or experience will be gratefully received, thank you.